# Select where combined with exists

Tags: query, exists

Table `dating_users`:

```
 user_id | username
---------+----------
      11 | taimoor
      13 | jacob
      14 | pi
(3 rows)
```

Table `dating_likes`:

```
 like_id | user_id | liked_user
---------+---------+------------
      54 |      11 |         13
      56 |      13 |         11
      57 |      11 |         14
(3 rows)
```

I want to find likes where a user has liked someone, and that someone has liked them. Here's my query:

`select like_id from dating_likes where user_id = 11 and exists(select like_id from dating_likes where liked_user = 11);`

Result:

```
 like_id
---------
      54
      57
(2 rows)
```

That should have resulted with only the first row, since `54` is a like where the `user_id = 11` and there is a like `56` where `liked_user = 11`. Like `57` should not show up, since it's not mutual - all that's true is that the `user_id` is 11.

Comment: It would be better if you mention the Database engine you're working with. whether it's Oralce,Sql-server, Mysql, etc.I've rewritten your query with exists and posted it as answer

Comment: Your query answers the question if 11 liked x and if y liked 11. You need to add predicate for x=y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about it as two different likes that have to equal:

```
select b_likes_a.liked_user
from dating_likes a_likes_b
join dating_likes b_likes_a
  on  a_likes_b.user_id = b_likes_a.liked_user
  and a_likes_b.liked_user = b_likes_a.user_id
where a_likes_b.user_id = 11
```

`a_likes_b` and `b_likes_a` are table aliases of `dating_likes`.

From this we also see that `like_id` is meaningless and could be omitted. `(user_id,liked_user)` is a sufficient primary key.

Comment: Thanks Dan! I submitted an edit to correct the column names.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution

```
select t.*
from dating_likes t
where exists (select t1.like_id,t1.user_id
              from dating_likes t1
              where t.user_id = t1.liked_user and
                    t.liked_user = t1.user_id)
```

The output is this :

```
like_id  User_id   Liked_user
 56       13          11
 54       11          13
```

I don't know which solution(using Join or Exist) is better in terms of performance but I like to know if anyone wants to share their opinion.
Thanks